# Matrix multiplication performance numpy and eigen c++

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to compare matrix multiplication performance of eigen using C++ and numpy.

Here is c++ code for matrix multiplication

```
#include<iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip> 

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;


    int main()
{
    time_t begin,end;
    double difference=0;
    time (&begin);
    for(int i=0;i<500;++i)
    {
    MatrixXd m1 = MatrixXd::Random(500,500);
    MatrixXd m2 = MatrixXd::Random(500,500);
    MatrixXd m3 = MatrixXd::Zero(500,500);
    m3=m1*m2;
    }
    time (&end); 
    difference = difftime (end,begin);
    std::cout<<"time = "<<std::setprecision(10)<<(difference/500.)<<" seconds"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

compiling using `g++ -Wall -Wextra -I "path-to-eigen-directory" prog5.cpp -o prog5 -O3 -std=gnu++0x`

Output:

`time = 0.116 seconds`

Here is python code.

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(500):

    m1=np.random.rand(500,500)
    m2=np.random.rand(500,500)
    m3=np.zeros((500,500))
    m3=np.dot(m1,m2)

stop_time = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time = {} seconds'.format((stop_time-start_time)/500))
```

Output:

`Time = 0.01877937281645333 seconds`

It looks like C++ code is 6 times slower as compared to python. Can someone give insights whether I am missing here anything?

I am using Eigen 3.3.4, g++ compiler (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0, python 3.6.1, numpy 1.11.3. Python running with spyder ide. Using Windows.

**Update:**

As per answer and comments, I updated the code.

C++ code compiled with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -I "path-to-eigen-directory" prog5.cpp -o prog5 -O3 -std=gnu++0x -march=native`. I couldn't get `-fopenmp` to work - there seems no output if I use this flag.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip> 

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    time_t begin,end;
    double difference=0;
    time (&begin);
    for(int i=0;i<10000;++i)
    {
    MatrixXd m1 = MatrixXd::Random(500,500);
    MatrixXd m2 = MatrixXd::Random(500,500);
    MatrixXd m3 = MatrixXd::Zero(500,500);
    m3=m1*m2;
    }
    time (&end); // note time after execution
    difference = difftime (end,begin);
    std::cout<<"Total time = "<<difference<<" seconds"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Average time = "<<std::setprecision(10)<<(difference/10000.)<<" seconds"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Total time = 328 seconds
Average time = 0.0328 seconds
```

Python code:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(10000):

    m1=np.random.rand(500,500)
    m2=np.random.rand(500,500)
    m3=np.zeros((500,500))
    m3=np.dot(m1,m2)

stop_time = timeit.default_timer()
print('Total time = {} seconds'.format(stop_time-start_time))
print('Average time = {} seconds'.format((stop_time-start_time)/10000))
```

Running with `runfile('filename.py')` command using spyder IDE.

Output:

```
Total time = 169.35587796526667 seconds
Average time = 0.016935587796526666 seconds
```

Now the performance with eigen is better, but not equal to or faster than numpy. May be `-fopenmp` can do the trick, but not sure. However, I am not using any parallelization in numpy, unless it is doing that implicitly.

Comment: make the test running for a few minutes. The time you provided is not statistically sound.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Matrix multiplication depends heavily on the BLAS/Linpack Library you are using. You have to add which one numpy and eigen uses. (for example Intel MKL)

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your benchmark:

1. You are benchmarking the system `rand()` function which is very costly!
2. You're missing the compiler `-march=native` to get AVX/FMA boosts
3. You're missing `-fopenmp` to enable multithreading.

On my quad i7 2.6GHz CPU I get:

```
initial code:                       0.024s
after replacing `Random` by `Ones`: 0.018s
adding `-march=native`:             0.006s
adding `-fopenmp`:                  0.003s
```

The matrix is a bit too small to get good multithreading benefits.

Comment: (1) I am using `rand()` equivalent in python code, so it should be costly there too (if it is really). (2) Updated the question with `-march=native`. It made code faster(3) Unfortunately I couldn't get to work `-fopenmp`

Comment: but python's rand() might be faster, please check by replacing `Random` by `Ones` to eliminate this source, then please specify your CPU. Mine is 4 years old, so you should be able to get similar performance. We currently observe a factor larger than 5 (even without openmp), so there must be something wrong on your side.